# webaudio not working with ionic using crosswalk on android device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, web-audio-api, crosswalk

I created an ionic webrtc app that runs perfectly when using `ionic serve` (on web browser, witch is normal). but was not working at all on the device since the `getUserMedia` function was not able to execute.

The solution i found is to install crosswalk, update permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and add the meta tag on the `index.html` for content security: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy: media-src: 'self' mediastream">`

Now, i have a working ionic webrtc app but only video, the audio is not working. the android app is able to diplay video with its audio, but seems to only send video without audio !

**My settings :**

***Permissions on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file :***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
```

***Output of the `ionic info` command :***

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v0.12.2
```

***Output of the `ionic browser list` command :***

```
iOS - Browsers Listing:

Not Available Yet - WKWebView
Not Available Yet - UIWebView


Android - Browsers Listing:


Available - Crosswalk - ionic browser add crosswalk
         Version 8.37.189.14 Published
         Version 9.38.208.10 Published
         Version 10.39.235.15 Published
         Version 11.40.277.7 Published
         Version 12.41.296.5 Published
(beta)   Version 13.42.319.6 Published
(canary) Version 14.42.334.0 Published

Available - Crosswalk-lite - ionic browser add crosswalk-lite
(canary) Version 10.39.234.1 Published
(canary) Version 10.39.236.1 Published

Available - Browser (default) - ionic browser revert android
Not Available Yet - GeckoView
```

***Content of the `ionic.project` file :***

```
{
  "name": "WebRtc app",
  "app_id": "",
  "browsers": [
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "browser": "crosswalk",
      "version": "16.45.421.19"
    }
  ]
}
```

what i dont understand is that in the `README.md` file in the crosswalk plugin folder i can read the following :

```
    ### Benefits

* WebView doesn't change depending on Android version
* Capabilities: such as WebRTC, WebAudio, Web Components
* Performance improvements (compared to older system webviews)
```

so, how it comes that crosswalk claims that webrtc and webaudio is working, but only the video is working on my app, not the audio ??

For the lack of other devices, the app was only tested on two armv7 android smartphones, i cant say what happens in an x86.

Thanks for your answers, since i really need to know if im in the right direction, or just fallback to native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It had nothing to do with crosswalk, it was a permission problem. Just added the following line to the list of permissions and the video and the audio are both working fine.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I couldn't resolve it that way. (Working with Crosswalk-cordova-plugin though)

Comment: Hey there, do you have a sample of your code anywhere? I am having the exact same issue (using Twilio Video JS library) but adding the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission did not fix it.  I already ask for RECORD_AUDIO and CAMERA at runtime and like you, the camera works fine.  Audio only works when I am testing in browser.

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg what about this line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />` ?

Comment: @dafriskymonkey Not more than 5 minutes after posting my comment, I finally figured it out.  I did not need to add RECORD_VIDEO (did you?) but I did have to change the order in which I was asking for the audio permissions.  MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS first, then RECORD_AUDIO.  Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg oh ! I didnt even know that order matters, good to know, thanks to you too mate.