# cordova : android 23 need "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" permission at runtime

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

Im using WebRTC with cordova and I made the huge mistake of upgrading the version of android in the play store from 22 to 23. (apparently no way to revert this situation)

Now I must ask for the permissions at runtime. Everything is ok for now, but for WebRTC communication my app needs this particular permission "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS". For camera, microphone and location permissions I use [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) using those methods : `requestCameraAuthorization`, `requestMicrophoneAuthorization` and `requestLocationAuthorization`.

I tried `requestRuntimePermission` method with this as argument `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` but its not working since `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permission` doesnt contain 'MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS' permission. Here is the list of available permissions :

[image]

Im pretty much sur that the problem is the lack of 'MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS' permission, since I had the same problem with android 22 (no audio) because I was not including it in the config. see this [old SO post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344819/webaudio-not-working-with-ionic-using-crosswalk-on-android-device)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` is not a "dangerous" permission that can be requested at run-time on Android: [see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups) the full list of "dangerous" permissions which need to be requested at run-time.

Comment: All the permissions are set in the config.xml to ensure backward compatibility with previous android versions. So i still need to ask for that permission at runtime.

Comment: `So i still need to ask for that permission at runtime`. No, you don't and you can't - it's not a run-time permission, so only requires an entry in the manifest. Have you checked that your entries from config.xml are ending up in AndroidManifest.xml? Until recently (cordova-cli@6.4.0), a 3rd-party plugin such as [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) was required for this.

Comment: For me, app crash after adding MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission to config.xml. Inside <config-file> tag.